# Error in 'Launch Configurations' in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I need to create a Runnable Jar file using Eclipse Indigo for Java EE. I right clicked on my project, and select "Export". In the new Dialog box, I selected `Java > Runnable Jar file` and clicked next.

Now, I need to provide 'Launch Configurations'. The problem here is, the drop down menu only contains projects I have already deleted, my current project is not even listed. How can I solve this?

Comment: I think there is a clean all button somewhere. Eclipse stores lots of mumbo jumbo in its caches. Oh yeah, and you need to create the run config manually.

Comment: Have you ever run it from within Eclipse or manually created a Run configuration? If not you won't have a run configuration.

Comment: @greg-449: Yes I did run it via Eclipse

Comment: @user1186155: I did clean it. Still the same issue.

Comment: I know this is a rubbish thing to say but have you tried restarting eclipse? Also, when you run your main Java class in eclipse, after it runs, if you click the down arrow next to the green play button (the 'Run As' button), is the class you just ran listed there?

Comment: @Matt: I even re started the comjputer. Now I am tired with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Under  `Run > Run Configurations > Java Application (Left side panel)` it was refering to my deleted old project. I deleted it, closed the configuration and re run the configuration. `Run > Run Configurations > Java Application (Left side panel)` to add my new project. With this, the existed issue is gone.